# Instantiating an N-ary tree from a CSV file

Tags: java, csv, tree

I'm coding up an N-ary tree representation of file system hierarchies, where each node contains some information about the file/folder it represents.

```
public class TreeNode {

    private FileSystemEntry data;
    private boolean directory;
    private TreeNode parent;
    private ArrayList<TreeNode> children;
    private int numChildren;
    private int key;
```

The tree is stored as its own object because I'm going to compare several trees

```
public class DirectoryTree {

    private TreeNode Root;
    private int numNodes;
    private TreeNode Focus;
    private LocalDateTime date;
    private long totalSizeOnDisk;
```

And here's the FileSystemEntry class for reference

```
public class FileSystemEntry {

    private Path path;
    private String name;
    private long sizeOnDisk;
    private FileTime created;
    private FileTime lastModified;
```

I need to write each node to a file so that it can be reloaded at a later date, in order to compare the trees at two different times. I can easily write the variables from FileSystemEntry, and the Date from DirectoryTree to a CSV in order to recreate each FSE and its respective node, but I can't wrap my head around how I would then know for sure which node is a given nodes parent, in order to rebuild the tree.

At first glance, a breadth first traversal and the numChildren or even key from TreeNode seems to be enough information, but I haven't been able to implement a solution. Am I thinking along the right lines or am I over complicating the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `ObjectOutputStream` to write your `DirectoryTree` objects into files. Therefore you have to implement the `Serializable` interface to all of you classes that you want to write.

This will preserve your structure/hierarchy and you wont have to mess around with the relation between the nodes.

*Example:*

```
public class TreeNode imlpements Serializable {

    private FileSystemEntry data;
    private boolean directory;
    private TreeNode parent;
    private ArrayList<TreeNode> children;
    private int numChildren;
    private int key;

}

public class DirectoryTree imlpements Serializable {

    private TreeNode Root;
    private int numNodes;
    private TreeNode Focus;
    private LocalDateTime date;
    private long totalSizeOnDisk;

}

public class FileSystemEntry imlpements Serializable {

    private Path path;
    private String name;
    private long sizeOnDisk;
    private FileTime created;
    private FileTime lastModified;

}
```

To write an object into a file:

```
public class IOTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File file;

        // create your Tree
        DirectoryTree dirTree;
        file = new File("filename");
        dirTree = createTree();

        // write object into file
        writeTree( dirTree, file );

        // read object from file
        DirectoryTree newDirTree;
        file = new File("filename");
        newDirTree = readTree( file );

    }

    public static DirectoryTree createTree() {

       // create here your tree

    }

    public static void writeTree( DirectoryTree tree, File file ) {

       FileOutputStream fos;
       ObjectOutputStream oos;

       try { 
           fos = new FileOutputStream( file );
           oos = new ObjectOutputStream( fos );

           oos.writeObject( tree );
           oos.flush();

           oos.close();
       } catch( IOException ioe ) {
           ioe.printStackTrace();
       }

    }

    public static DirectoryTree readTree( File file ) {

       DirectoryTree loadedTree = null;
       FileInputStream fos;
       ObjectInputStream oos;

       try { 
           fos = new FileInputStream( file );
           oos = new ObjectInputStream( fos );


           // you have to cast your object into a DirectoryTree,
           // because read() will return an object of type `Object`
           loadedTree = (DirectoryTree) oos.read();

           oos.close();
       } catch( IOException ioe ) {
           ioe.printStackTrace();
       }

       return loadedTree;

    }

}
```

Comment: woah! Didn't know that was a thing! Looks way simpler than what I was trying to do. Thinking about it, of course that's a thing haha. Thanks! I'll give it a go and get back to you

Comment: Fits in nicely with my code, but I'm getting an interesting IOException: NotSerializableException: java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime

I assume that means that the FileTime object isn't serializable?

Comment: Do you think it would be easier to store created and lastModified as long in the nodes so they can be serialized, and converted to FileTime if I ever need them, or to convert them to long before I write them to file, and then back again after